# SQL query last instance before current range

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that pulls all studies from the previous week based on the av_summary column. I need to add a column that will pull the study prior to the most recent study no matter how long ago the previous study was performed. I only need the date of the last study. f.creation_datetime is the column both current study and previous study would come from.

```
select distinct
 f.patient_name
,t.patient_mrn
,p.accession_number
,p.performed_start_time
,p.procedure_id
,SUBSTRING(CAST(s.av_summary as NVARCHAR(MAX)), CHARINDEX('This suggests 
 the stenosis', CAST(s.av_summary as NVARCHAR(MAX))) , 
 LEN(CAST(s.av_summary as NVARCHAR(MAX)))) as AV_Summary
,(select TOP 1 (p1.performed_start_time)
  from dbo.T_TCS_PROCEDURE as p1
  where 
  p1.patient_id = p.patient_id
  and
  p1.performed_start_time < p.performed_start_time 
  and p1.procedure_type_id = p.procedure_type_id
  order by p1.performed_start_time DESC
 ) as Last_Echo

from dbo.folders as f
 join dbo.T_TCS_PROCEDURE as p
  on p.procedure_id = f.procedure_id
 join dbo.T_ECHO_SUMMARY as s
  on s.procedure_id = f.procedure_id
 join dbo.T_CON_DISPATCHER_EVENT_TRACK as t
  on t.procedure_id = f.procedure_id
```

where 
    CAST( f.creation_datetime AS DATE ) > DATEADD( DAY, -14, CAST( GETDATE() 
    AS DATE))
   and 
    CAST(s.av_summary as NVARCHAR(MAX)) like '%This suggests the stenosis is%'
   and 
    LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(t.patient_mrn))) > 0

Comment: Try to add what kind of result does this query returns and what kind of result is expected

Comment: Hi you could `left join` the table to itself on the condition that the date is earlier and select `max(joined_table.creation_datetime)` to determine the previous date.

Comment: Why does your query have a GROUP BY when it's not doing any aggregation?  I think you're going to have to take it out to get it to work.

Comment: I removed the GROUP BY, but I am still getting NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out how to get the data I wanted for the previous study. I had to correlate the subquery on a couple different columns and I used a completely different table. The database I am working with is a complete mess, but I managed to figure it out. The company that created the database couldn't even figure it out. Thank you all for your help on this. It is much appreciated.

```
    ,(select TOP 1 (p1.performed_start_time)
      from dbo.T_TCS_PROCEDURE as p1
      where 
      p1.patient_id = p.patient_id
      and
      p1.performed_start_time < p.performed_start_time 
      and 
      p1.procedure_type_id = p.procedure_type_id
      order by p1.performed_start_time DESC
     ) as Last_Echo
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to add a column that will pull the study prior to the most
>   recent study no matter how long ago the previous study was performed.

Add the column as a subquery that gets the TOP 1 date before the date of the current row's study.

Comment: Would I do this in select? what would the syntax be for this?

Comment: https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-server-20-using-subqueries-in-the-select-statement/ especially the paragraph on "Correlated Subqueries".

Comment: I tried adding a subquery, but i do not believe it is working correctly. it is just putting the previous day in the new column. see new query in code above.

Comment: You need to add an ORDER BY to your subquery, so that it gets the most recent date before the `f.creation date`, and not just any date.   Also you need to correlate the subquery on `procedure_id` so it doesn't grab the creation_date of an un-related procedure.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and now it is just pulling NULL values.

Comment: In the ORDER BY in your sub-query, you need to use the `f1` date, not the `f` creation date.   Also specify `DESC` for the order.